# Stored Procedure Nesting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

1. Is it possible to create a stored procedure that executes another stored procedure on a different server?
2. What if the second stored procedure requires SA roles and the server does not allow SQL Server logins? Is is still possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, the answer is yes and following is the explanation: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/06/sql-server-executing-remote-stored-procedure-calling-stored-procedure-on-linked-server/

For the second question, you should have the required rights to access the server and execute the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto Sonam's answer, you can use sp_addlinkedsrvlogin to add a login-mapping for the remote server.  It handles Sql Server (non-Windows) accounts